# Flutter Align not working inside row contained in column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a row with 3 items: an `IconButton`, a `Text`, and a `SizedBo`x with a width set. The row is inside a `Column` with anther child which is `Expanded`.

I'm trying to get the `IconButton` to align to the TOP of the row. I thought that wrapping this inside an `Align` with alignment topCenter would work, but it doesnt:

[image]

I can't figure out why. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat")),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 80,
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 0.7,
                      child: Placeholder(),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: Placeholder(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Interestingly, if I remove the outer `Column`, the `Align` works:

[image]

I'd like to understand why, and how to resolve this layout issue. Note that **I don't want to set the `Row` crossAxisAlignment to start, because this would then misalign the `SizedBox` containing the `Placeholder` to the top instead of the center of the row**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the `Row` in an `IntrinsicHeight` to fix it, so like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                    ),
                    const Expanded(child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat")),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 80,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 0.7,
                        child: Placeholder(),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: Placeholder(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's because the `Row` doesn't know what height it is before all children are rendered. So the `Align` doesn't know what it's height should be. Without the `Column` it does know because then the `Row` knows it will have all available space

Comment: Also using `IntrinsicHeight` is a valid option but it's an expensive widget in terms of performance

Comment: @omarhatem it's true that it's relative expensive, but I think it's the only way to truly get the desired behavior. Your answer would have better performance but wouldn't give the exact desired height

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Never used `IntrinsicHeight` before, just reading the docs now. So, it's expensive because the layout engine has to basically render the Row first in  a separate pass? Does it have to do this only because of the Text? (I assume it can work out how big the SizedBox / AspectRatio and IconButton is beforehand)

Comment: @JamesAllen I'm not sure exactly how it works. It seems that just leaving out the text doesn't make the Align work either. I just know that without the IntrinsicHeight, the children of the Row will try to make their height as small as possible or something, I guess to minimize the height of the Row itself. Using the IntrinsicHeight in some way makes the children first layout themselves as if their wasn't an IntrinsicHeight and then doing it again, but now knowing what the highest height was in the previously layout. How it works I don't know

Comment: @IvoBeckers Every now and then I come across a situation where Align doesn't work like I expect, so I'm trying to gain a more fundamental understanding. What you say is starting to make sense, because IntrinsicHeight only seems to be needed when the Row is nested inside the Column with another Expanded child, which will tell the Row to be as small as possible. Without the outer Column, the Row is told that it can expand as much as it wants

Comment: @JamesAllen whenever you have time I suggest to read [this page](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) .  It's quite a long page and most you probably already know, but it's very insightful about how Flutter lays out its widgets

Answer (score 0):

`Align` is not working cause the `row` is not given a height so it doesn't know on which basis it will align its child

you can solve this by either giving the row a fixed height (which is not preferable if the text can grow)

or you can solve it by wrapping the `Row` in an `Expanded` widget and control its size with respect to the other `Expanded` widget through `flex` attribute

like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                    ),
                    const Expanded(child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat")),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 80,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 0.7,
                        child: Placeholder(),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Placeholder(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and the output is this

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer the other answer using `IntrinsicHeight` because of text scaling - there is a large range of text size possible depending on the user's device font size (small / medium / large / extra large) so it would be tricky to figure out what flex amount to give to the row